# login by facebook for mobile applications

Tags: android, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I am new on developing mobile application and I want to use facebook login for my application by using spring boot. What is the best practice for this to perform it on client side or server side?

If it would be normal username/password login, I would perform it on server side. But by login by facebook, application will be directed to facebook pop-up. Therefore I do not know what is the correct way to perform this. Anybody can advice?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Facebook SDK for this. This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) will help you get started.